# Access the attributes of a sister child via the parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations

So I've been looking all over and can't seem to find the correct conceptual explanation/technical process for this, and quite possibly am approaching it incorrectly.

I have 2 child models, connected by the same parent, I want to access the attributes of CHILD B from an Index view on CHILD A :THROUGH an instance of the parent.

**High level overview**

```
    Property
   /        \
Order      Owner
```

Basically I have an index page showing all the open `Orders`, each `Order` must have a `Property`(parent) and every `Property` has an owner. So I'm in the `Orders` index page and I want to see the `first_name` of the `Property's Owner`, how can I access that?

If I do something like:

```
@order.property.owners.first_name
```

I get a an error `undefined method`, however if I do:

```
@order.property.owners
```

I don't receive an error but rather:

```
    #<Owner::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f8a85368988>
```

shows up in my view, along with all the other correct information.

**Models**

```
Property
has_many :orders
has_many :owners
accepts_nested_attributes_for :owners

Owner
belongs_to :property

Orders
belongs_to :property
has_many :owners, through: :property
accepts_nested_attributes_for :owners
```

**Orders Controller**

```
  def open_orders
@open_orders = Order.where(status: "Open").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
###@orders = Order.all
###@properties = Property.find(@orders.property.id)
###@owners = Owner.find(@properties.owners.id)
render 'orders/open'
```

end

^ Commented out stuff I was trying but was not working, including it incase I'm just a little bit off somewhere.

**`Open_orders` View**

```
<% @open_orders.each do |order| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= order.client_id %></td>
    <td><%= order.order_number %></td>
    <td><%= order.property.address1 %></td>
    <td><%= order.property.owners %></td>
    <td><%= order.order_update ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
    <td><%= order.status %></td>
    <td><%= order.task %></td>
    <td><%= order.created_at %></td>
    <td><%= link_to fa_icon("edit"), edit_property_order_path(order, order.property.id), class: "m-r-xs", remote: true, data: { 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => '#orders-modal'} %></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your model definition, an `order` has *multiple* `owners`..thus you are getting active record collection of owners instead of single object.

There are 2 ways to handle this,

1. Loop through the collection and get the names
2. Pluck all the owner names, which is I think you are looking for

You must preload the owners to avoid *n+1* queries

In your controller

```
@open_orders = Order.where(status: "Open").includes(:owners).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
```

In your view

```
<td><%= order.owners.pluck(:first_name).join(',') %></td>
```

**Update**

To get the `full_name` of the owner, you can define a method in your `owner.rb` as

```
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

In your view

```
<td><%= order.owners.map(&:full_name).join(',') %></td>
```

Comment: That was pretty much it, thanks again @Md. Farhan Memon!

The only thing is that I have First_name and Last_name in two separate fields, so when I have multiple owners it joins everything on a comma, I tried putting `order.owners.pluck([:first_name1, :last_name1], [:first_name2, :last_name2]).join(', ')` to try to keep them together, any ideas? Other than that, your answer was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: ahhhhhhh of course! Didn't think of that but now that you said it, it makes total sense. Thanks again, really appreciate it!